# Parse Error on Switch Input Call Typescript and React Issue (React/Typescript)

Tags: java, json, reactjs, typescript

I'm using React/Typescript, and I'm having an issue with a toggle input. On page load, I have a function that's calling a service, to check if a json value for a toggle is set to true. On page load, the service is being called but the json value isn't being set correctly, causing an error on the page. On a save() function, i'm getting this error message. How can this be fixed? Code added to bottom.

**TLDR: Getting an JSON Parse Error on Toggle Input**

`` message: "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `boolean` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `boolean` out of START_OBJECT token↵ at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 349] (through reference chain: gov.defense.business.mpp.dto.MentorApplicationChecklistDto["mentorInfoComplete"])" ``

```
interface IState {
  mentorInfoComplete?: boolean;
}


 public componentDidMount = () => {
    // this.load();
    this.fetchApplication();
  }

  public render = () => {

  <FormControlLabel
              control={
              <Switch
              color="primary"
              checked={mentorInfoComplete}
              onChange={this.handleMentorInfoChange}
              value={mentorInfoComplete}>
              Toggle
              </Switch>
            }
              label="NO"
              labelPlacement="start"
            />

private fetchApplication = async () => {
    const { match } = this.props;

    try {
      const result = await axios.get(
        `/mentorApplication/${match.params.applicationId}/review`
      );

      const application = _.get(result, `data`);
      const mentorInfoComplete = _.get(result, `data`);

      this.setState({
        application: fromJS(application),
        mentorInfoComplete: fromJS(mentorInfoComplete),
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the error is happening on the server which is taking the call. As per my understanding it is happening in jackson which is a json parser. So mostly it could be because of the payload which the server receives or expects to receive.

Comment: i was wondering if i'm passing it through correctly? it's expecting a boolean value, which i'm trying to pass through. not sure if i'm making a mistake.

Comment: try accessing that url normally. like `http://localhost:1234/mentorApplication/1234/review`

Comment: same issue when I'm attempting to post the value. On page load it should set the value to how it was previously saved in the json payload, but for some reason it's not accessing it.

Comment: that is because the api call results in an error and when _.get() is called it returns undefined when it doesn't find the specific key-value pair. Check the docs: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get . This error is still because of how the data processing happens in the get request which is fired on page load.

Comment: right right... that makes sense... i'm reading through the docs, but i'm not sure what exactly i'm looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186902/discussion-between-klvenky-and-kory-j-campbell).